# Segmentation fault with more than N processes

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi, glibc, contiguous

I am struggling with an invalid memory reference when calling SUB EXC_MPI (MOD01), and precisely at MPI_StartAll (commented).

```
! ********** file mod01.f90 ************ !
MODULE MOD01

implicit none
include 'mpif.h'
! alternatively
! use mpi
! implicit none
PRIVATE
! ...
INTERFACE exc_mpi
   MODULE PROCEDURE exc_mpi
END INTERFACE
PUBLIC exc_mpi

CONTAINS

subroutine exc_mpi (X)
!! send and receive from procs PN0 <-> PN1 and PN0 <-> PN2
real, dimension (ni:ns, m, l), intent(inout) :: X

logical, save :: frstime=.true.
integer, save :: mpitype_sn, mpitype_sp, mpitype_rn, mpitype_rp
integer, save :: requests(4), reqcount
integer       :: istatus(MPI_STATUS_SIZE,4), ierr

if (frstime) then
   call exc_init()
   frstime = .false.
end if
call MPI_StartAll(reqcount,requests,ierr)         !!  <-- segfault here
call MPI_WaitAll(reqcount,requests,istatus,ierr)
return

contains

subroutine exc_init

integer :: i0, ierrs(12), ktag

reqcount = 0
ierrs=0
ktag = 1

! find i0

if ( condition1 ) then
! send to PN2
   call MPI_Type_Vector(m*l, messlengthup(PN2), ns-ni+1, MPI_REAL, mpitype_sn, ierrs(1))
   call MPI_Type_Commit(mpitype_sn, ierrs(3))
   call MPI_Send_Init(X(i0, 1, 1), 1, mpitype_sn, PN2-1, ktag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, requests(reqcount+1), ierrs(5))
! recieve from PN2
   call MPI_Type_Vector(m*l, messlengthdo(PN0), ns-ni+1, MPI_REAL, mpitype_rn, ierrs(2))
   call MPI_Type_Commit(mpitype_rn,ierrs(4))
   call MPI_Recv_Init(X(nend(irank)+1, 1, 1), 1, mpitype_rn, PN2-1, ktag+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, requests(reqcount+2), ierrs(6))
   reqcount = reqcount + 2
end if

if ( condition2 ) then
!   send and rec PN0 <-> PN1
   reqcount = reqcount + 2
end if

return
end subroutine exc_init

end subroutine exc_mpi

! ...

END MODULE MOD01
```

Which the calls come from:

```
! ********** file mod02.f90 ************ !
MODULE MOD02

use MOD01, only: exc_mpi 

IMPLICIT NONE
include 'mpif.h'
! alternatively
! use mpi
! implicit none
PRIVATE

! ...

INTERFACE MYSUB
   MODULE PROCEDURE MYSUB
END INTERFACE
PUBLIC MYSUB

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE MYSUB (Y)

IMPLICIT NONE
REAL,    INTENT(INOUT)   :: Y(nl:nr, m, l) ! ni<=nl, nr>=ns
REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:,:) :: Y0
!...
allocate ( Y0(ni-1:ns, 1:m, 1:l) )

DO i = 1, icount

   Y0(nl:nr,:,:) = Y(:,:,:)
   call exc_mpi ( Y0(ni:ns, :, :) )           !  <-- segfault here
   call mpi_barrier (mpi_comm_world, ierr)
   Y0(ni-1,:,:) = 0.
   CALL SUB01

END DO
deallocate (Y0)
RETURN

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE SUB01
!...
   FRE: DO iterm = 1, m
      DIR: DO iterl = 1, l
         DO itern = nl, nr
!            Y(itern, iterm, iterl) = some_lin_combination(Y0)
         END DO
      END DO DIR
   END DO FRE

END SUBROUTINE SUB01

! ...
END MODULE MOD02
```

Segmentation fault is raised at runtime when MAIN (actually a sub in a module) call MYSUB (se code above) for the second time.
The error is not systematic, in the sense that the program works if splitting the job up to a certain number of processes, say NPMAX, which depend on the decomposed array. With more procs than NPMAX, the program segfaults.
More on the environment conditions:

- almost [compiler + mpi independent]: the same issue arise with [gfortran+ompi], [gfortran+mpich] and [ifort+mpich].
- occurs on deb-based (glibc) mini hpc and pcs (no problems on "serious" nec, sun, ibm)

As can be seen, MOD02 passes to the exchange procedure (MOD01) a sliced array Y0 which is non contiguous. The only way I could almost overcome the fault (NPMAX growing by one order of magnitude) is to exchange the dimensions back and forth, but this causes the execution slowing down approximately a factor of 2.
I bet that permanently exchanging X/Y/Y0 dimensions will solve but I do not want to loose efficiency of the nested cycles like SUB01 (first dimension is much bigger than the others).

Indeed, MOD02 creates a temporary array. Doing that explicitly doesn't solve the issue.

Forcing allocation an heap or stack doesn't solve.

Any hint out there?
Thanks for reading

UPDATE:
Initialising at each call ( call exc_init() out of the if statement in sub exc_mpi ) does solve, but it is totally inefficient since MAIN (not listed) is looping a lot.

UPDATE2 (after @Gilles):
This workaround does not work either, even if passing a contiguous array (Y1, in this case) and mpi is not creating a temp.

```
SUBROUTINE MYSUB (Y)

IMPLICIT NONE
REAL,    INTENT(INOUT)   :: Y(nl:nr, m, l) ! ni<=nl, nr>=ns
REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:,:) :: Y0, Y1
!...
allocate ( Y0(ni-1:ns, 1:m, 1:l) )
allocate ( Y1(ni:ns, 1:m, 1:l) )

DO i = 1, icount

   Y1(nl:nr,:,:) = Y(:,:,:)
   call exc_mpi ( Y0 )           !  <-- segfault here
   call mpi_barrier (mpi_comm_world, ierr)
   Y0(nl:nr,:,:) = Y1(nl:nr,:,:)
   Y0(ni-1,:,:) = 0.
   CALL SUB01

END DO
deallocate (Y1)
deallocate (Y0)
etc ...
```

Comment: Should the array `requests` not be of the size of the number of processes?

Comment: No, size(requests) >= max number of requests (2 send + 2 rec in this case)

Comment: Are you sure that neither `ni` nor `ns` change between iterations of `i`?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, but they do not. I'm decomposing only once. If there were a redefinition of the indexes in the code, that would probably cause segfault also with np<NPMAX.

Comment: But if you only pass a non-contiguous slice of `Y`, there's no guaranty that from a call to the next you pass the same address as it is likely to be a temporary. Therefore, the persistante communication channel gets broken since you registered an address that may no longer be valid.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for pointing this out . Did try with the edit in UPDATE2. No success though :(

Comment: It looks to me as if you have mistyped `reqcount` as `nrequests` in `exc_int`. The lack of `IMPLICIT NONE` doesn't really help in such cases.

Comment: @HristoIliev Sorry, miscopying when putting relevant stuff together..edited

Comment: Still `requests(nrequests+2)` in the call to `MPI_Recv_init`.

Comment: When you use `use mpi` and not `include mpif.h` you get more checks about the correctness of your MPI calls. It differs how many checks from implementation to implementation, but it can be really helpful.